# How to translate "drive"?

Tags: verbes, transports

For instance, if I was simply going to say, "I drove there," would that be "J'y ai conduit," or is it "J'y ai roulé," or… ?

And also, "I drove to the park"… would that be "J'ai conduit au parc"? What if I wanted to specify "I drove by the park", or "I drove around the park"… would I have to use a different verb, like "J'ai passé le parc en voiture"? Ça se dit? And, "I drove around the park," could that be translated as "J'ai conduit autour du parc"? That's definitely wrong.

Just checking if this is straightforward or if I have it wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bien que la plupart du temps on puisse traduire *to drive (a vehicle)* par *conduire (un véhicule)*, on traduira la forme intransitive *to drive (somewhere)* par

> - aller en voiture (quelque part)
> - rouler (en direction de quelque part)

Ainsi, on pourra traduire

- *I drove there / to the park* en *Je suis allé là-bas / au parc en voiture*
- *I drove by / around the park* en *J'ai roulé vers le / autour du parc*

A noter que pour ton dernier exemple, *J'ai conduit autour du parc* est une traduction tout à fait valide.

Comment: Pourquoi se servir de *là-bas* plutot que *y*? "J'y suis allé" n'est pas valide?

Comment: *J'y suis allé* est parfaitement valable, bien sûr.

Comment: j'y suis allé imply than the persons know the localisation where the people went.

Comment: _Rouler_ fonctionne aussi pour les vélos, alors qu'en anglais on dit _ride_ plutôt que _drive_.